# Need help help modifying a npm package in Vue3.JS

Tags: node.js, vuejs3

I want to build a mindmapping tool using Vue.

I found this vue3-mindmap component. The issue I'm facing is it that it's not dynamically updating the mindmap when I update the underlying data. I think the issue is it uses a clone of the modelValue to build the mindmap and hence it's not reactive.

```
#App.Vue 
<template>
  <mindmap v-model="state.data"
  :edit=true
  :add-node-btn=true></mindmap>
  <div >{{ state }} </div>
  <button @click="updateData">Update Data</button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive} from 'vue'
import mindmap from 'vue3-mindmap'
import 'vue3-mindmap/dist/style.css'

export default {
  components: { mindmap },

  setup() {
    const state  =reactive({data:[{ 'name': 'Old Data' }]})
    function updateData() {
      state.data=[{ 'name': 'New Data' }]
    }
    return  {state,updateData}
  }
}
</script>
```

I have little understanding of JS libraries and I'm struggling to fix the source code and use it in my project. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the `modelValue` is getting internally copied to a new ImData object.

```
emitter.emit('mmdata', new ImData(cloneDeep(props.modelValue[0]), xGap, yGap, getSize))
```

I haven't found any simple way to manipulate the internal data outside of the Mindmap plugin. There is already the issue [After the v-model binding data is updated, the brain map page is not updated accordingly](https://github.com/hellowuxin/vue3-mindmap/issues/33) (Chinese) about the problem.

### Workaround

If it does now work other way, you can always use the following ugly workaround.

You can force Vue to destroy the mindmap using `v-if` and recreate it again from scratch.

Here is the sample how to achieve it

```
<script setup>
import { ref, nextTick  } from 'vue'
import mindmap from 'vue3-mindmap'
  
  const data = ref([{ 'name': 'Old Data' }])

  function updateData() {
     data.value = [];
     nextTick(() => {
        data.value = [{ 'name': 'New Data' }];
     })    
  }
</script>

<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/vue3-mindmap@0.5.12/dist/style.css" media="screen" />  
   <mindmap v-if="data.length > 0" v-model="data" :edit=true :add-node-btn=true></mindmap>
  <div >{{ data  }} </div>
  <button @click="updateData">Update Data</button>
</template>
```

And the [working playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)